# Dynamic Text in Rails Best Practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm implementing an explainer sidebar that shows different text based on the user's current page.

What is the best way to do this? Loading content from a `yaml` file, having a `switch case` method in my user class, or using `content_for:` are a few ideas that come to mind, but am interested in best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the differences are based on the current page then I would recommend content_for. That way the relationship is obvious and limits hard to find connections.

Comment: Even if it's a decent amount of text? I was thinking it would make sense to have all the different explainer texts grouped together, so if I ever needed to edit them I wouldn't go to the view to do so.

Comment: That's a good point. But if you do that I would still recommend tying it through the view. You could put the content in a yaml file and have your views put it directly from there into the content_for. That would allow you to share the same text across multiple pages if needed also.